# Can not set java.lang.Long field Event.idEvent to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a entity "Event" and when i want select a Event by id, i have this error :
Can not set java.lang.Long Event.idEvent to java.lang.Long

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long Event.idEvent] by reflection for persistent property [Event#idEvent] : 1
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1538)
    org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    fr.eni.sortircom.dal.dao.hibernate.HibernateRegistrationDAO.selectById(HibernateRegistrationDAO.java:19)
    fr.eni.sortircom.bll.RegistrationManager.selectParticipantEvent(RegistrationManager.java:27)
    fr.eni.sortircom.servlet.ShowEventServlet.doGet(ShowEventServlet.java:28)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long fr.eni.sortircom.bo.Event.idEvent] by reflection for persistent property [fr.eni.sortircom.bo.Event#idEvent] : 1
    org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:75)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4940)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4640)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:297)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:347)
    org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:495)
    org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeSet(EntityType.java:288)
    org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:53)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:645)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2006)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1920)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2695)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2678)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2512)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2507)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:224)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1538)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1561)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1529)
    org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    fr.eni.sortircom.dal.dao.hibernate.HibernateRegistrationDAO.selectById(HibernateRegistrationDAO.java:19)
    fr.eni.sortircom.bll.RegistrationManager.selectParticipantEvent(RegistrationManager.java:27)
    fr.eni.sortircom.servlet.ShowEventServlet.doGet(ShowEventServlet.java:28)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field fr.eni.sortircom.bo.Event.idEvent to java.lang.Long
    sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
    org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4940)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4640)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:297)
    org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:347)
    org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:495)
    org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeSet(EntityType.java:288)
    org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:53)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:645)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2006)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1920)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2695)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2678)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2512)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2507)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:224)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1538)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1561)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1529)
    org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    fr.eni.sortircom.dal.dao.hibernate.HibernateRegistrationDAO.selectById(HibernateRegistrationDAO.java:19)
    fr.eni.sortircom.bll.RegistrationManager.selectParticipantEvent(RegistrationManager.java:27)
    fr.eni.sortircom.servlet.ShowEventServlet.doGet(ShowEventServlet.java:28)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

here is my entity Event :

```java
public class Event implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_event")
    private Long idEvent;
```

and here the select by id :

```java
 public Event selectById(Long id) {
        Session session = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
        Query q = session.createQuery("FROM Event WHERE idEvent=:id");
        q.setParameter("id", id);
        List<Event> events = q.getResultList();
        Event event = events.get(0);
        return event;
    }
```

I have check the Long and he is correct. And i have the same request for a another Entity, and it works. I do not understand.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Can you post your full Event class ?

Comment: Does something prevent you from using `findById(Long)` on your `EventRepository`?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch in your parameters i.e you try and specify a Long as the parameter for a User type:

You change it in one of two ways: I have added This is with one sample example
.

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Collaborator c WHERE c.user.id = :userId AND c.task.id =:taskId")
void deleteUserFromTask(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("taskId") Long taskId);
```

or

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Collaborator c WHERE c.user = :user AND c.task = :task")
void deleteUserFromTask(@Param("user") User user, @Param("task") Task task);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will actually help, but seems like you've chosen very complex way. You can simply implement `CrudRepository<Event, Long>` interface with your repository and do the select using its `findById` method.

This is actually really easy, just follow those simple steps.

I. Implement the `CrudRepository`.

```
public interface EventRepository implements CrudRepository<Event, Long> {}
```

II. Use `findById` method in your service with `EventRepository` autowired.

```
Long id  = ...;
Optional<Event> event = eventRepository.findById(id);
```